# Java check if Stack contains certain class

Tags: java, types, stack

I use Stack to store  objects of different classes. I want to pop until I meet certain Class. But I do NOT want to pop anything if that stack doesn't contain required Class. I have extended Stack like that:

```
  private class ClassStack<T> extends Stack<T>
  {
    public boolean containsClass(Class type)
    {
      for (int c = 0; c < size(); c++)
        if (type.isInstance(get(c)))
          return true;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

But I'm unsure about implementation. First, I'm unsure whether get() for Vector that I use is O(1) or not. Second, I don't know if I should touch those methods. Maybe there is a better way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you have to store in your ```ClassStack``` the class that are added to your stack. In fact, you shouldn't be able to go through all your stack elements without popping them out.

Comment: @D.Lawrence Stack has a [get method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html).

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake me and SDJ posted some answers to your question. Let us know, if they helped you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadocs for Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) state:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

To check that the `Deque` contains an object of a class or not, you can use a stream operation, which avoids having to use inheritance. An example helper method to do this:

```
private static boolean contains(Class<?> test, ArrayDeque<?> input) {
    return input.stream()
            .map(Object::getClass)
            .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(test));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, your `get()` method is O(n). 
I assume you can use another approach. What about holding a Map object, that will collect classes, added to stack? In your ClassStack:

```
Map<Class, Int> classMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void push(T object) {
    Class c = T.getClass();
    if (!classMap.contains(c)) 
        classMap.put(c, 1);
    else classMap.put(c, classMap.get(c) + 1);

    //then add the element to stack itself  
}

@Override
public T pop() {
    // pop the last element
    Class c = last.getClass();
    classMap.put(c, classMap.get(c) - 1);
    if (classMap.get(c) == 0) classMap.remove(c);
}

public boolean containsClass(Class type) {
    return classMap.contains(type) && classMap.get(type) > 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: for clearance I wrapped all calls to `T.getClass()` to a local variable `Class c`

Comment: To avoid a memory leak, you could erase the item when the count reaches 0. But It would probably not be a problem in practice.

Comment: @bastet you are absolutely right, it would be cleaner to remove a reference to Class that is no longer present in the stack, thank you - I edited my answer

Comment: That's a good idea, and I actually thought about it. But didn't want to complicate it to level of handling two data structures. If there won't be any better ideas from community or myself, I'll accept yours. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If the class you look for is always the same for a given stack, the simplest may be to extend Stack and store the class as an attribute, as well as the number of objects of this class stored in the stack so far (update when you `pop` and `push`). If the class is not always the same, Steyrix's answer provides a more general approach by storing all classes.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class ExtendedStack<T> extends Stack<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7548225233082854568L;
    private final Class<?> c;
    private int count = 0;

    public ExtendedStack(Object o) {
        this.c = o.getClass();
    }

    public boolean hasClass() {
        return count > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public T push(T o) {
        super.push(o);
        if (c.isInstance(o)) {
            count++;
        }
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public T pop() {
        T o = super.pop();
        if (c.isInstance(o)) {
            count--;
        }
        return o;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExtendedStack<Number> s = new ExtendedStack<>(1);
        s.push(1.0); System.out.println(s.hasClass());
        s.push(1); System.out.println(s.hasClass());
        s.pop(); System.out.println(s.hasClass());
    }
}
```

Note that here I pass an object to the constructor, and get its class. It's also possible to pass a `Class` object, but then you will need `Class.forName`.